# To Print page content dynamically which includes multiline text box

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Can you please help me in implementing following functionality in Asp.net.

I have a page where the data is displayed dynamically.
In this data generation, i have multiline text box with many other controls in the page.
I want to implement print functionality where i can print entire page content including multiline text box complete data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the control over the print page style then follow [this link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=92).
If you want to simply print the page then a simple button like this

```
<asp:Button ID="printButton" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick="javascript:window.print();" />
```

is sufficient.

Comment: nope.... it consist of multiline text box rite.... If we use above script. Data in multiline text box is not getting displayed

Comment: for getting data that has been entered in text box you have to put that data in a div element or as literal control. You can also try to replace input control to div if it seems easier in final html that is needed to print.